# sending as base64 and save to byte oid

Tags: database, postgresql

I try to write script to save some files into a table with OID (byte[]) 
I find lo_import but this is not exactly what I want. I would like to set base64 instead of path to file. Is there any diffrent method? If You don't understand ->

what I don't want

```
INSERT INTO table VALUES (lo_import('path'))
```

what I want

```
INSERT INTO table VALUES (lo_import('base64 (maybe something else)'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write a function (this is server side only solution)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION lo_import_bytea(path text)
RETURNS bytea AS $$
DECLARE
  loid oid;
  result bytea;
BEGIN
  loid := lo_import(path);
  result := lo_get(loid);
  PERFORM lo_unlink(loid);
  RETURN result;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Attention - only super user can use `lo_import` function, because this function has access to file system on server side. So probably this function should be `SECURITY DEFINER` type. In this case, this function can be security hole, and probably some form of white list for path can be good idea.

Usual way is using libpq (client library) function [`lo_import`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/lo-interfaces.html#LO-IMPORT) that returns oid of imported object. This oid can be used as parameter for function `lo_get`. This function transform LO object to bytea type. Transformed value can be inserted to table. After this, the LO object described by oid can be removed.